# How to show receiving messages separately in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using pusher chatkit to receive the messages. I am receiving messages successfully. But, now I want to show these messages individually just like a chat application should.

```
onNewMessage: message => {
  if (message.sender.id === '{{Auth::user()->name}}{{Auth::id()}}') {
    var arr = [];
    i = 0;

    $(message).each(function() {
      arr[i++] = message.text;
      console.log(arr);
      $('.sender-box').append(arr);
    });
  }
```

Here the sender-box is the div in which I am showing the messages. But instead of showing messages as Message A Message B in separate boxes, it shows in one. What is wrong here? I am trying to store the messages in an array, but they are not coming in the same array.

This is what I did now:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="sender-box p-2 mb-2"></div>
 </div>
```

And, the Jquery looks like the same but with ES6. But, both of the messages are coming in a single box. I want them to be in separate boxes.

Comment: What is your parameter `message`? How it looks?

Comment: If I console.log(message) then I get this: e

attachment: undefined

createdAt: "2018-07-16T11:23:17Z"

id: 2434103

roomId: 11699802

roomStore: e {store: e, initialize: function, set: function, get: function, pop: function, …}

senderId: "Teacher4"

text: "Hi, Teacher"

updatedAt: "2018-07-16T11:23:17Z"

userStore: e {store: e, initialize: function, set: function, get: function, fetchUser: function, …}

e Prototype

Comment: Please edit the question and attach it in readable format.

Comment: Hi, I have edited.

Comment: I said _in readable format_... try to print `console.log(JSON.stringify(message))` and formta the output with a tool like [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your messages doesn't stored in the array because any time you recreate the array and remove the previous items. Instead, use the following code:

```
const arr = [];
onNewMessage: message => {
  if (message.sender.id === '{{Auth::user()->name}}{{Auth::id()}}') {
    arr.push(message.text);
    $('.sender-box').append(`<div class="message">${message.text}</div>`);
  }
```

Instead of saving the next index, this code uses the arrays' `push()` method, that insert a new item to the end of the array: See [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

Comment: Edited again, it helped but I mentioned what is required. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. For your help.

Comment: I need an another help, if you can help do lmk.

Comment: @Rob Open a new question, I am and other people are here to help :-)

Comment: Hey, `arr.push(message.text)` is supposed to create an array in arr. So, if I will `console.log(arr)`, will it show arr as [a,b,c,d]?

Comment: @Rob I don't understand.